# rotation log4net doesn't rewrite the same log-file

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I want to limit my rotation-log to 500 MB.

So after 500MB the same log file will be overridden.

Now configuration opens a new log-file after 500MB.

How can I fix this?

```xml
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="D:\Products\Logs\MamClientServices\MamClientServiceLog.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <StaticLogFileAppName value="false"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="500MB"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff}||[%thread]||%-5level||%logger||%message%newline"/>
      </layout>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="WARN"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="infrastructure" additivity="false">
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="system" additivity="false">
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am missing something obvious you tell log4net to maintain 5 files:

```
<maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
```

See the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.MaxSizeRollBackups.html).

Comment: thanks. I'll mark your answer as soon as the time gate allows

Answer (score 0):

To get it to open the same logfile, you will likely need to do:

```
<StaticLogFileAppName value="true"/>
```

Right now, you have that set to false. According to the [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.StaticLogFileName.html),that is what specifies if a new file should be created.